# Set different headers for every child level using PrimengTreeTable and Angular 8

Tags: typescript, angular7, primeng, angular8, primeng-treetable

I need to set different headers for child-level data. I am using PrimengTreeTable with Angular 8. Parent records can have an nth level child. For every level I want different headers to be shown.
It's like showing a different table at every level. Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*ngIF` to control. When you expand row, trigger an event that activate the `ngIF` make the column visible.